# Karate scripts run too fast sometimes, can we have any other option other than delay(2000) to make it slow

Tags: karate

I am running karate script which is running too fast even i am not able to see whether particular page appears on screen or not. Or script just marked the test as pass without even going to that page.

i know we can use waitFor() function for any element but that is not possible in my case.

Is there anything that we can use other than delay()

Comment: you really want to find a way to use waitFor().  I've never seen a test script with a timed delay that wasn't flaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options below:

1. Use the Karate extension to step-through and debug: https://youtu.be/_BlUgR9noEI
2. [`configure driver`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver) has `highlight` and `highlightDuration` options, try those
3. You can use `karate.stop()` as a one-off: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#debugging